# Wifi connection keeps dropping on 16.04 (Realtek RTL8812AE)

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

I am new to Linux. I just recently install Ubuntu 16.04 on my desktop at work. The wireless connection here works great in Windows 10 on the same computer, but keeps dropping (and sometimes not coming back for long minutes) every so often. It sometimes works all day, and then the next day it drops every minute.

I can sometimes bring the connection back quickly using

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

though it doesn't work every time.

The output of

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

is

```
*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: wlp1s0
   version: 01
   serial: 10:be:f5:07:1c:8e
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.10.0-28-generic firmware=N/A ip=132.69.196.209 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:126 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7100000-f7103fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: enp4s0
   version: 09
   serial: 38:d5:47:27:07:4a
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168f-1_0.0.5 06/18/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:123 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7000000-f7000fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
```

I am happy to provide more information (I'm just not quite sure what might be required).

Help!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is common with that chipset.

I had that problem too until I downgraded my kernel to 4.8.0-58, then the problem disappeared, but after a while (and maybe some system updates) it started to happen again.

After some research and looking at logs I noticed that this only seemed to happen on Access Points (note: still on the 4.8.0-58 kernel) where I get either authentication timeouts or power reductions of the WiFi Adapter in the `dmesg`, which I unfortunately don't have a fix for.

The only thing I have been able to evade this is to use an external WiFi Adapter, but I guess that won't help you much.

The only thing I can advise is to revert to an older kernel (for me the version 4.8.0-58 helped), you'll find lots of tutorials about this on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks Tim. Are there no downsides to downgrading to an older kernel?

Comment: I didn't find any. Of course there are some security holes that aren't fixed in older kernel versions, but in my opinion I rather want to use WiFi than having all of the latest security holes fixed.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that on Monday and report back/accept your answer.