# How to fix my network connection in newly installed ubuntu 16.04 .how do i install the correct driver?

Tags: 16.04, networking, dual-boot, wireless

I need help. I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 as dual boot along side windows 10. It connects to the network but the internet is extremely slow or doesn't work at all.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8812] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: D-Link System Inc RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1186:3305]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
```

Thank you so much in advance.

```
sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for mike: 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 13
       serial: d8:cb:8a:5e:92:0f
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:32 memory:f7200000-f723ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 01
       serial: e4:6f:13:28:91:61
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.4.0-31-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.107 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:31 ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f7100000-f7103fff
```

---

```
mike@mike-MS-7821:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8812] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: D-Link System Inc RTL8812AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1186:3305]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae

mike@mike-MS-7821:~$ modinfo rtl8821ae
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8821ae/rtl8821ae.ko
firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8821aefw.bin
description:    Realtek 8821ae 802.11ac PCI wireless
license:        GPL
author:         Realtek WlanFAE <wlanfae@realtek.com>
srcversion:     B9E24DCC76240A48AEEF94E
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008821sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v000010ECd00008812sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        rtlwifi,rtl_pci,btcoexist,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           swenc:Set to 1 for software crypto (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           ips:Set to 0 to not use link power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           swlps:Set to 1 to use SW control power save (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           fwlps:Set to 1 to use FW control power save (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           msi:Set to 1 to use MSI interrupts mode (default 1)
 (bool)
parm:           debug:Set debug level (0-5) (default 0) (int)
parm:           disable_watchdog:Set to 1 to disable the watchdog (default 0)
 (bool)
parm:           int_clear:Set to 0 to disable interrupt clear before set (default 1)
 (bool)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. The troubleshooting is no machine-specific but it is (wireless) chipset-specific and we need to know which one you have in order to help you.

Comment: does any of that mean anything to you?

Comment: Yes, it does. RTL8812AE is problematic: https://askubuntu.com/questions/942590/wifi-connection-keeps-dropping-on-16-04-realtek-rtl8812ae and https://askubuntu.com/questions/633473/15-04-32-bit-unstable-wifi are just examples, there are many more and no straightforward definitive answer.

Comment: so maybe just buy a new wireless card?

Comment: alternatively , could i just choose a different distro of linux like debian and have it work with my current hardware or do drivers work for everything linux? sorry for my ignorance i am trying to get something working

Comment: I would like to make a couple of remarks but before that I must make it clear that I'm no expert in wireless (I tend to choose hardware I already know works fine) do, the comment above comes from what I could gather by searching here using the chipset's name. That said, it's important to understand: 1. Drivers are at a kernel level; working differently in another distro is unlikely. 2. *Maybe* there's a good solution already but I couldn't find it.

Comment: thanks for your time at the least i appreciate it . I decided to scrap my dual boot all together and dust use a windows dev environment . I will eventually get around to buying a wireless card that works with ubuntu.